# Correlation calculation

Tags: statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcCzS.png)What is the correlation of the scatterplot? Is it equal to zero because half of the values show correlation equal to one while another half show values of correlation equal to -1 (-1+1)? I think it can be zero because half of the scatterplot is perfectly positively associated while the latter half is perfectly negatively associated. But can it be so simple that I just add them up?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vH9X.png)What is the correlation if the scatterplot has three parts, first perfectly positively associated, second perfectly negatively related and the last perfectly positively associated? My answer is 1+-1+1= 1. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I have shown my work: -1+1. Just wanna check if it is correct and seek explanation.

Comment: "-1 + 1" is not work, it is a guess.

Comment: That's my work for the scatterplot: Half -1, half 1.  If I know the full answer, I don't need to ask the question, right?

Comment: Look, there is a "how to ask a good question" guide, and I linked it to you. You clearly did not read it. I can tell you, from experience, that your question, as it stands, is not up to site standards. You can either improve it or not, it's up to you. But if you do not, then you should not expect to get an answer.

Comment: I did read the guide roughly. I am not giving no clue just throwing put the question without any input. I just want to know more about maths and believe here is a great place for knowledge. I added more details so it should be ok.

Comment: The ‘curve’ I am referring to is the scatter plot. Sorry for not being detail-minded.

Comment: Your curve does not look what you are describing in the text. In the text, you say that "the curve has three parts, first perfectly positively associated, second perfectly negatively related and the last perfectly positively associated." This does not appear in the image. So I still do not even know what exactly it is you are asking. I don't know how anyone could help you if you are unwilling to put in the effort to explain what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Sorry. Let me improve it later.

Comment: Just as a piece of advice, when you improve the question, you can write a comment starting with "@5xum" and I will be notified about the comment. That way, I can then try to answer the question!

Comment: @5xum I have improved the question. Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: By "the correlation of the scatterplot", do you mean the correlation coefficient $R$ of the data?

Comment: Yes, that’s my meaning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot just add up correlations of parts of your data.

In particular, take for example the case where the samples are:

$$\{(0,0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2.5, 2), (3, 1.5), (3.5, 1)\}.$$

For this collection, the correlation coefficient of $\{(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)\}$ is $1$, and the correlation coefficient of $\{(2.5, 2), (3, 1.5), (3.5, 1)\}$ is $-1$. However, the correlation coefficient of the entire set is **not** $0$. It is, in fact, about $0.6069$.

Comment: Btw, can you show the calculation for the correlation 0.6069?

Comment: @Alan Just apply the formula in Eq3 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample